# Meaning of "rape" in "Rape of Nanking"

Tags: meaning-in-context, archaic-language

Someone used "the rape in Nanking" rather than "the rape of Nanking", and I want to explain why it's the latter, but I don't fully understand the phrase myself!

What was the meaning of the word "rape" in the phrase "Rape of Nanking"?

Wiktionary gives several related meanings for the word, including seizing by force, or plundering destroying and despoiling, as well as forced sex. Which of these meanings was intended?

Comment: I don't think this is actually archaic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A "rape" of a city involves an orgy of arson, looting, killing, and yes, rape. Within this context, that is exactly what happened to Nanking in 1937. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre

A synonym for "rape" is "violate." When a city is systematically violated by enemy soldiers (in the economic sense), it may be said to be "raped." But such a large-scale violation of a city involves the actual rape of a large number of its women, practically by definition. Soldiers that are allowed to loot and murder by their officers usually do not "abstain" just because a potential victim is a woman.

Answer (score 4):

The [Rape of Nanking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanking_Massacre) (a.k.a. *Nanking Massacre*) was a mass murder and a [war rape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_rape) happened in  the city of [Nanking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanjing). *War rape* could means *sexual rape* or a situation where girls and women are forced into prostitution or sexual slavery by an occupying power.

As for why it is *Rape of Nanking*, *of* is the preposition that is usually used in such cases. It is similar to [Massacre of Glencoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_of_Glencoe), [Massacre of Vassy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_of_Vassy), or [Massacre of Thessalonica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_of_Thessalonica). *Of* is used after nouns formed from verbs; the noun after *of* can be either the object or the subject of the action. In these case, what follows *massacre of* is the name of a town whose inhabitants has been massacred.

Comment: kiam, do you think that here, on ELL, there is a lack of votes in reference to the answers. I remain perplexed thinking to this problem and seeing that these two answers don't still have any vote. Can this phenomenon be correlated to the fact that the visits for day are diminished during the last week?

Comment: Or maybe some questions are not thought to be much interesting.

Comment: @Carlo, kiamlaluno: I haven't upvoted either answer because it seems to me they both imply that *The Rape of Nanking*, for example implies figurative or real sexual assualt. But the sense of **rape** here in such constructions is OED's *The act of taking something by force; esp. the seizure of property by violent means; robbery, plundering.* Non-consensual sexual intercourse is a different meaning (sexual rape may well occur during the *rape of [some populated location]*, but it doesn't *have* to be part of such a "ransacking/massacre".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't care whether you upvote my answer or not, but, if you read my last two sentences, I took great care to word my answer to indicate that the "rape" of a city need not include sexual assault: _widespread plundering along with violence of horrific proportions._

Comment: @J.R.: I'm sure both you and I are aware that *the rape of [place]* needn't (and normally *doesn't*, imho) have any implications of "forced sex". And I'm not suggesting your answer is "incorrect" on that front - it's just that it doesn't spell the point out clearly for others who *don't* already know that. And who might assume *rape = loot, sack, plunder* is a metaphoric extension from the *sexual assault* sense - when it's actually an earlier and independent sense, from which the sexual meaning arose later, I believe.

Comment: @Fumble: The O.P. asked about which preposition was appropriate (_of_ or _in_), and already mentioned the multifaceted uses of the word _rape_ **in the question** ("including seizing by force, or plundering destroying and despoiling..."). I didn't see a need to belabor the point.

Comment: @J.R.: I read it as OP is asking what *rape* means in this specific context, not "which preposition is correct?". It's not exactly the same meaning, but I'd say it's closer to [The Rape of the Lock](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheRapeOfTheLock?from=Main.TheRapeOfTheLock) than [the Mumbai rape case](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/topic/MUMBAI-rape)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The first sentence is about "'the rape in Nanking' versus 'the rape of Nanking'." I know that is not explicitly asked, but the OP's reason for asking the question is saying why one of those phrases is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

If the person was talking about a single rape incident during the massacre, then *in* would be a correct preposition. However, when referring to an entire incident of systematic war crimes and atrocities committed against a particular region and its populace – than *of* is more fitting.

The fact that a rather famous book was entitled [*The Rape of Nanking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rape_of_Nanking_%28book%29) might make *of* a more familiar preposition. If I heard the phrase "the rape of Xanadu," then I would assume the speaker was referring to either the rape of a person named Xanadu, or the rape of a city named Xanadu. In the latter case, I would assume that we are not talking about a few isolated cases of rape, but much more widespread plundering along with violence of horrific proportions. When the word *rape* is applied to a city, the word implies an entire city has been victimized, not just a few individuals in it.

Comment: Yes, J.R, in fact there is [The Rape of the Sabine Women](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rape_of_the_Sabine_Women), too.